# How to solve matrix equation $AXH+AHX−BH=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to solve matrix equation $AXH+AHX−BH=0$? All matrices are square, $A$, $B$ known constant matrices and invertible, $H$ can take any value, $X$ represent the solution to be found.

I have seen about the Sylvester Equation like in this post [Solving a matrix equation $AX=XB$ in a CAS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39906/solving-a-matrix-equation-ax-xb-in-a-cas), but I'm not sure how to apply it because of the presence of matrix H.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation is still linear in $X$, that means that if you consider $X$ a vector, call it $\Xi$ (made up of all the entries of the matrix $X$ in a definite order) you can write it in the form

$$
Q\Xi = W
$$
where $W$ is the vector likewise made of the entries of the matrix $BH$. Now the problem reduces to finding $Q$ and its inverse (you should check if $Q$ is invertible, it is not obvious to me that it will be).

The matrix $Q$ represents the action of $A$ and $H$ over $X$ sometimes acting on the left and sometimes on the right. I you call the right-acting operator $^R$ and the left one $^L$ then in fact you have $Q = A^L \otimes H^R + (AH)^L \otimes {\bf 1}^R$ and you can write the matrix as a tensor product, and then invert it. To simplify matters you could also start multiplying your equation on the left by $A^{-1}$, but the method to solve remains the same.
Your answer is then $\Xi = Q^{-1} W$ which you can map back to $X$ in matrix form.

Comment: Thanks Rogelio, sorry I have edited the post, maybe you can check it again and let me know your opinion. Thanks.

Comment: Well, even with the new version it is still true that you can proceed in the same manner by finding $W$, then $Q$ then $\Xi$ and finally $X$. Changing to the base where $H$ is diagonal will not really help because we do not know that $X$ will be diagonal in such case, we end up having to solve a linear system anyway, which we could have done earlier inverting $Q$

Comment: I didn't have any previous knowledge of tensor matrix, but i have do some research after you give me your answer, but I have a question respect to $$Q=A^R⊗H^L−(AH)^R⊗1^L$$ It shouldn't be something like $$Q=A^L⊗H^R+(AH)^R⊗1^L$$? And when you say (AH)^R should I assume a different form for AH or the matrices are the same $$AH=(AH)^{R}$$?. How do I know who is W if H can take any value? and finally if A is a identity matrix, because if it actually that. Should the tensor be $$H^R⊗1^L+H^L⊗1^L$$ if I am right in the previous question?

Comment: Actually it should be a + sign, I edited the answer. No matter what $H$ is, you can compute $W$ by multiplying arbitrary unknown components of $H$ by known components of B. The actual problem is that you don't know a priori if $Q$ will be invertible for any $H$, I don't think it will be. If $Q$ is non invertible the system has no solution. To obtain the components of $Q$ from the components of $H$ you may use collective indices that label the tensor product (index is labeled by two letters $ij$) you have the matrix $Q_{ij,kl} = H_{ik}\delta_{jl} + H_{jl}\delta_{ik}$

Comment: $AH$ has the same matrix form as $(AH)^R$, but the $^R$ is just to emphasize that it acts on the right, it is just the order I chose for the tensor product, i.e. $D\otimes G$, $D$ acts always on the left and $G$ on the right. The form you gave for the case $A= {\bf 1}$ is correct: $H^R\otimes 1^L+H^L\otimes 1^L$. I changed the roles of $^R,^L$ in my answer above as they were mixed up, now they're fine.

Comment: I found just one particular solution for X putting an specific value to H and what I did for Q was $$Q=H⊗1^L+1^L⊗H^{T}$$, but with other values of H it doesn't work, I mean XH+HX-BH=0 (because A is identity) just with the particular H I have chosen. So what can I conclude? Numerically matrices are: $$B=\begin{pmatrix} 0.5287 & 0.2708 \\ -0.9522  & -0.4732\end{pmatrix}$$, The H matrix which I choose is $$H=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0  & 2\end{pmatrix}$$.

Comment: There seems to be some mix up with the way in which $Q$ is defined. $^T$ usually stands for the transpose, but you should take no transposes anywhere. I will write the details with the particular matrices you have given, but this will be in a few hours. The point is inverting $Q$ which will be a $4\times 4$ matrix, this can be done numerically also, provided $Q$ is invertible, that will not be a problem for the $H$ you have given.

Comment: Yes T is the transpose, I actually did $$Q=H⊗I+I⊗H^T$$ by following some properties of the Kronecker product, and I found a 4 x 4 Matrix $$Q=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 &  0 & 0\\0  &   3   &  0  &   0 \\   0  &   0  &   3  &   0\\ 0  &   0  &   0  &   4 \end{pmatrix}$$. Then I compute $$W=[ 0.5287, -0.9522,  0.5417, -0.9465]^T$$, which is vectorizing the product $BH$ and then I obtain  $Ξ=Q^{−1}W$ and reconstructing $Ξ$ into a matrix which will be $$X=\begin{pmatrix}0.2643 & 0.1806\\ -0.3174  &-0.2366 \end{pmatrix}$$, which is solution because if I compute XH+HX-BH=0. But let me know your method.

Comment: And why only with the particular H I chose does it work and with others not?

Comment: You should not use the transpose. $Q$ is simply $Q= H\otimes 1 + 1 \otimes H$. I added an answer below. It works for that particular $H$ because such $H$ is diagonal.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, the equation
$AXH + AHX - BH = 0$
is equivalent to
$A(HX + XH) = BH.$

You say $A$ is invertible, so you can write 
$HX + XH = A^{-1}BH$
which is a Sylvester equation ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation)) and can be solved in CASes by the functions described in the answer to the post you linked, or as
$$(I_n \otimes H + H^T \otimes I_n) \operatorname{vec} X = \operatorname{vec}(A^{-1}BH).$$

If $A$ is *not* invertible, I would do as anbarief suggest. First solve
$$AY = BH$$
by solving
$$(I_n \otimes A) \operatorname{vec} Y = \operatorname{vec}(BH)$$
and then solving the Sylvester equation $HX + XH = Y$, e.g. through
$$(I_n \otimes H + H^T \otimes I_n) \operatorname{vec} X = \operatorname{vec} Y.$$

Of coure, if $A$ is not invertible, the equation $AY = BH$ have several or no solutions.

Comment: Fine. It is quite clear.

Comment: In fact, A is the identity matrix, I should edit the post, so should I do $$(In⊗H+H^{T}⊗In)vecX=vec(BH)$$, right?.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: But should I find the same solution for every H?, because as I change H solutions X are totally different.

Comment: If you change $H$, $X$ will change. You will not find a single $X$ that works for all $H$.

Comment: But I don't understand very good these results? And by other side I have found also from other answers that $$f'(X)=0$$ iff $$ I⊗(X−B)=−(X^t⊗I)$$ and I have done that finding a system of equations, equating on each side and what I have found is that B12 and B21 must be zero, it means B diagonal, but numerically they are not for that reason I concluded that there is not any critical point, because of the nature of B, so what about this result and the result I found with your equation, different solutions for each H.

Comment: Could you please provide some context? What is $f$ and how does it relate to your question?

Answer (score 1):

My idea is that ...
try to solve this equation first : 
$$  A(X_{1}) = BH $$, 
then solve, 
$$    XH+HX = X_{1}      $$ , by writing $XH + HX = H(X + H^{-1}XH) $. Then write the solution $X$ as a matrix that has $H$ for the diagonalization. Maybe it'll work..?

Comment: Thanks anbarief, sorry I have edited the post, maybe you can check it again and let me know your opinion. Thanks

Comment: But H can take any value, so how to solve X1 for any H?

Comment: What do you mean with "write the solution X as a matrix that has H for the diagonalization"? Could you please explain a bit the process after  $$XH+HX=H(X+H^{−1}XH)$$?

Comment: Well my $\textit{idea}$ is the solution $X$ is of the form a matrix such that the columns of $H$ are the eigenvectors of $X = HDH^{-1}$ , so  $H^{-1}XH = D$. So solve $H(X+D) = X_{1}$

Answer (score 0):

First vectorise the matrix $X$ so that $vec (X) =  (X_{11},X_{12},X_{21},X_{22})^T$, here I chose the ordering of the base as $11 \to 1, 12\to 2, 21\to 3, 22\to 4$ In this basis now compute $Q = H\otimes 1 + 1 \otimes H$ (No transpose anywhere!), in the case of a matrix $2 \times 2$ we obtain $Q$ in the basis we want as:

$$
Q = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
2H_{11}& H_{21}&H_{12}&0 \\
H_{12}& H_{11}+H_{22}&0&H_{12}\\
H_{21}&0&H_{11}+H_{22}&0 \\
0&H_{21}&0&2H_{22}
\end{array}\right)
$$
Now invert $Q$ and apply the inverse to $vec(BH)$, the result is $vec(X)$, that is the answer you want. I am guessing that what you did before was wrong because you used a transpose in $H$ (which should not be there), but it worked for the simple case you chose because that particular $H$ you wrote is diagonal so $H=H^T$ and they both agree. If you were to deal with a non-symmetric $H$ your answer would come out wrong because $Q$ was wrong. You should use the $Q$ I wrote above, that is a correct expression for $Q$, also valid when $H$ is not diagonal.

Comment: I have a question with respect to Q because I have computed $Q=H⊗1+1⊗H$ having H as $$H=\begin{pmatrix} H_{11}&H_{12}\\H_{21}&H_{22}\end{pmatrix}$$ and I have obtained: $$Q=\begin{pmatrix} 2*H_{11} & H_{12} & H_{12} & 0  \\ H_{21}&H_{11}+H_{22}&0& H_{12}\\ H_{21} & 0 & H_{11} + H_{22} &   H_{12}\\0 & H_{21}&H_{21}& 2*H_{22}\end{pmatrix}$$, which has some elements different from your Q matrix. Am I wrong in some part maybe?

Comment: The form of $Q$ depends of the basis you choose. I chose the ordering given above, but if you choose another ordering the matrix form of $Q$ may change. The form of $Q$ I gave was obtained by the componentwise expression above involving the Kronecker tensor. Other representations are possible. I suggest you check the componentwise definition of a tensor product for matrices, choose a basis you like and try it once again, or try to reproduce the matrix $Q$ I gave above from the equation $Q_{ij,kl}=H_{ik}\delta_{jl} + H_{jl} \delta_{ik}$

Comment: Hello, I have done what you have said but always changing H i find a different solution for X and after I have done what martini suggest because the problem comes from finding the critical points of a equation. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518760/critical-points-of-a-matrix-equation/518774?noredirect=1#comment1115660_518774 I mean this equation $$Id⊗(AX−B)=−Xt⊗A$$ lets me to find critical points. By using A as identity so it becomes $$Id⊗(X−B)=−X^{t}⊗I$$ and I have found something that was not coherent because solving the system as a system of equations as I said in next comment...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527059/critical-points-of-a-discrete-matrix-equation-x2-bx-c-0?noredirect=1#comment1130578_527059, i found a problem for X12 and X21 so I can conclude that there is no a critical point because of the nature of B.

Comment: If you have some comment please let me know.