# Critical points of a discrete matrix equation $X^{2}-BX-C=0$

Tags: matrices

Suppose a discrete matrix equation $$X^{2}-BX-C=0$$, B and C are known square constant matrices, B is invertible and C is not, X is the variable and also is a square matrix. Which is the method to find its critical points? Are these critical points the same as the solutions of the equation?

Comment: What do you understand by "critical points"? Roots?

Comment: In continuous functions I understand that critical points are points where all derivatives of the function become zeros, and I could find them by deriving the function and find its roots I mean f'(X)=0, in matrix equations is more complex but in general they are the same. Roots of a equation are solutions of the function in where it is always zero, but sometimes roots and critical points coincide for example sen(X)=X, that is why I am asking. But in the case of Discrete matrix equations how should I manage it?

Comment: Well, the derivative of a matrix function with respect to a matrix is a tensor of fourth order, hence I suggest using the Einstein notation to write an expression for the derivative. On the other hand, solving a nonlinear matrix equation is a very non-evident task; consider, for example, the equation $X^2=0$. The solutions form a manifold (in particular, there's  a continuum of solutions).

Comment: Ok, but threating with a discrete matrix equation, do derivatives also work? Because as I know the derivative of a function exist if it is continuous, for discrete equations how derivatives are?, what is an Einstein Notation, could you explain a bit?

Comment: [Einstein notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) is a way to simplify notations in large sums. As for derivatives, let $f:M_n(\Bbb C)\to M_n(\Bbb C)$ a matrix function. To find the derivative, you take $ij$-th component of $f(X)$ and derive it with respect to $X_{kl}$. Like this you obtain $ijkl$-th component of $\nabla_X f(X)$ (there're four indices, hence it's a tensor of fourth order).

Comment: Ok but the question is: Does the same method to find critical points apply for discrete equations? Because as I said, derivatives just exist if function is continuous.

Comment: Could you elaborate on `derivatives just exist if function is continuous`? We all know continuous functions that are nowhere differentiable...

Comment: I don't know, that is why I am asking, could you give some reference to read about it, and could you explain me please?

Comment: My previous comment was about what I knew but of course you can advice me and correct me if it is not true, that is why I am asking. As I have researched today of course it is possible to derivate a discrete function could you explain me the process more detailed about the tensor?.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11078/discussion-between-tzakrevskiy-and-gina-torres)

Comment: I have found something that not coherent respect to matrices, for example if matrices are 2 x 2 so equation $$I⊗ (X-B)=-X^t ⊗ I$$, left side you have a tensor 4 x 4 like $$\begin{pmatrix}X11-B11& X12-B12& 0& 0\\X21-B21 &X22-B22& 0 &0\\0& 0 &X11-B11 & X12-B12\\0& 0& X21-B21 &X22-B22\end{pmatrix}$$, and right side you have $$\begin{pmatrix}-X11& 0 &-X21& 0\\ 0 &-X11& 0& -X21\\-X12 &0& -X22 &0\\0& -X12& 0 &-X22\end{pmatrix}$$, so for X12 and X21 by equating both sides you have two equations one is X12=0 and other is that X12-B12=0 and for X21 you have X21=0 X21-B21=0. What happen with equation?

Comment: I have to add that B12 and B21 are not zero.

Comment: Well, in this case we obtain an equation with no solutions, i.e. the function has no critical points.

Comment: But, is the equation correct?

Comment: Yes, the equation is correct.

Comment: Ok so the results reflect the nature of B.